# Python noob hangman issue

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn Python and I'm writing a hangman game (which seems to be the 'hello world' of Python lol). I think I've about got it down, but the function I've written to replace hidden letters with the rightly guessed letter isn't working. For the life of me it seems like it should do what I want, but instead it will replace the entire hidden word with the one letter that was correctly guessed.

Here's the specific function:

```
def update_word_guessed(guess):
    global word_guessed
    for i in xrange(word.count(guess)):
        for x in xrange(len(word)):
            if guess == word[x]:
                word_guessed = word_guessed.replace(word_guessed[x], word[x])
                print word_guessed, 'wg[x] =', word_guessed[x], 'word[x] = ', word[x]
    return word_guessed
```

And here's the whole thing:

```
import random
import string

WORDLIST_FILENAME = "words.txt"

def load_words():
    """
    Returns a list of valid words. Words are strings of lowercase letters.

    Depending on the size of the word list, this function may
    take a while to finish.
    """
    print "Loading word list from file..."
    # inFile: file
    inFile = open(WORDLIST_FILENAME, 'r', 0)
    # line: string
    line = inFile.readline()
    # wordlist: list of strings
    wordlist = string.split(line)
    print "  ", len(wordlist), "words loaded."
    return wordlist

def choose_word(wordlist):
    """
    wordlist (list): list of words (strings)

    Returns a word from wordlist at random
    """
    return random.choice(wordlist)

# end of helper code
# -----------------------------------

# actually load the dictionary of words and point to it with 
# the wordlist variable so that it can be accessed from anywhere
# in the program
wordlist = load_words()
print '\n'
word = choose_word(wordlist)
word_guessed = []
for i in xrange(len(word)):
    word_guessed.append('-')
word_guessed = ''.join(word_guessed)
guesses = 10
correct_guesses = 0
letters_left = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'



def initiate_game():
    """ Starts game """
    print 'Welcome to the game Hangman!'
    print 'I am thinking of a word ', len(word), 'letters long'
    print '---------------'
    while guesses > 0 and correct_guesses < len(word):
        print 'You have ', guesses, 'guesses left.'
        print 'Unused letters: ', letters_left
        guess = str.lower(raw_input('Guess a letter: '))
        print word_guessed
        if check_letter_available(guess) == False:
            print 'Sorry, it looks like you have already used that letter.'
            continue
        check_guess(guess)
    if correct_guesses == len(word):
        print 'Congradulations, you win! '
        print word_guessed
    else:
        print 'You are out of guesses, the word was: ', word

def remove_guessed_letter(guess):
    global letters_left
    letters_left = letters_left.replace(guess, '~')
    return letters_left

def check_letter_available(guess):
    if letters_left.find(guess) == -1:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def update_word_guessed(guess):
    global word_guessed
    for i in xrange(word.count(guess)):
        for x in xrange(len(word)):
            if guess == word[x]:
                word_guessed = word_guessed.replace(word_guessed[x], word[x])
                print word_guessed, 'wg[x] =', word_guessed[x], 'word[x] = ', word[x]
    return word_guessed

#def update_word_guessed(guess):


def check_guess(guess):
    global guesses
    global correct_guesses
    guesses -= 1
    if word.find(guess) == -1:
        print 'Sorry, ', guess, 'is not a part of my word: ', word_guessed
        remove_guessed_letter(guess)
        return False
    else:
        correct_guesses += 1
        print 'Good job!'
        remove_guessed_letter(guess)
        update_word_guessed(guess)
        print word_guessed
        return True

##    for i in xrange(len(word)):
##        if guess == word[i]:
##            correct_guesses += 1
##            print 'Good job!'
##            remove_guessed_letter(guess)
##            update_word_guessed(guess)
##            print ' '.join(word_guessed)
##            return True
##        else:
##            print 'Sorry, ', guess, 'is not a part of my word: '.join(word_guessed)
##            remove_guessed_letter(guess)
##            return False


initiate_game()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're replacing all the dashes in the word with the letter here:

```
word_guessed = word_guessed.replace(word_guessed[x], word[x])
```

str.replace finds all instances of the first argument and replaces them with the second argument. You just want to change the one letter:

```
word_guessed = word_guessed[:x] + word[x] + word_guessed[x+1:]
```

There might be other problems, but that's the issue you've described. Enjoy!

Comment: Strings are immutable.  So you'd need something like `word_guessed = word_guessed[:x] + word[x] + word_guessed[x+1:]

Comment: Or just store word_guessed as a list

Comment: Thanks happydave! Edited above.

Comment: Thanks to you both! Can't believe I missed that lol. And yes, I originally had it as a list, ran into some other problems and the problem set suggested checking out all the string methods so I got the stupid idea to replace all the lists I had with strings. Made things much worse :-( But now it's working great thanks to ya'll, greatly appreciated!!